# Programmatically Tap a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield, edit

I have a `UITextField` named mainTextField, and a `UIButton` placed directly under it, called textButton. Ideally, when the user presses textButton, then mainTextField should think that a user has tapped their finger on it, causing a keyboard to pop up and editing to begin like it normally would. I've read through the docs and I have no idea which message send to use to accomplish this, does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: This is a personal app, I do not plan on submitting it to the App Store, so the funky reasoning is okay to do. Thank you for the concern though!

Comment: You're probably breaking a half-dozen user-interface guidelines by doing this, and your users are not going to expect this behavior.  They will expect to tap on the text field to bring up the keyboard, and click the button to submit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call `[mainTextField becomeFirstResponder]`.

And `[mainTextField resignFirstResponder]` does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'll accept the answer when it allows me to in 10 minutes.

Comment: your answer must work for him, but this will lead him off-direction...