# Get Text Input WITHOUT UITextField Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uitextinput

I'm making an app and I want the user to be able to input text without having them actually click on a UITextField (have it open after the game ends for a scoreboard), is there some way to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279781/programmatically-tap-a-uitextfield

Comment: @AhmadF While the answer is the same, that solution doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Comment: Then how you accepted the answer?

Comment: Because it worked when I tested in on another project, so I probably did something wrong other than that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the following in the `viewDidLoad` of scoreboard, or whatever the entry point of that view is.

```
yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I would assume not, just call yourTextField.isHidden = false right before calling the code in the answer, it should work fine :)

Comment: Do I need to call something after saying .becomeFirstResponder?
I initilized it with `nameInput.isHidden = false
        nameInput.becomeFirstResponder()
        lbNames[0] = nameInput.text!` and the textfield is simply `let nameInput: UITextField = UITextField()` do I need to do something else?

Comment: Should be fine.

Comment: The cobe above doesnt call the text input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just:

```
<#your_text_field#>.becomeFirstResponder()
```

after the game ends.

This will produce the "same" effect as a tap on the `UITextField`. If this is on a new `UIViewController` you can place it on `viewDidAppear`, otherwise you can assume everything is already loaded and simply call it anywhere.

Comment: Do I need to call something after saying .becomeFirstResponder? I initilized it with nameInput.isHidden = false nameInput.becomeFirstResponder() lbNames[0] = nameInput.text! and the textfield is simply let nameInput: UITextField = UITextField() do I need to do something else?